# Docker Apache HTTPD with Certbot

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to run Wordpress on Docker along with MySQL. Here are the contents of the docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - blog-vol:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secretpass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wpuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: blog:v1
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpuser
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: pass
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile.blog
volumes:
    blog-vol: {}
```

blog:v1 (Image built separately)

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN echo 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list 
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-certbot-apache  -t stretch-backports
```

Dockerfile.blog

```
FROM blog:v1
RUN certbot certonly -a standalone  --agree-tos  --non-interactive --dry-run --email email@gmail.com --domains "abc.net"
```

When I run

```
docker-compose up
```

I see that Apache & MySQL come up and I can access wordpress. But I do not see Dockerfile.blog execute.

I can SSH in to the container and run the command, but of course that will require a restart of Apache, which will kill the container.

I tried running the commands directly.

Here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - blog-vol:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secretpass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wpuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: blog:v1
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpuser
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: pass
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
     build: .
     command:
       - /bin/bash
       - -c
       - |
         certbot certonly -a standalone  --agree-tos  --non-interactive --dry-run --email uhsarp@gmail.com --domains "batchu.net"
volumes:
    blog-vol: {}
```

Here are the logs

```
...
db_1         | 2019-04-25T01:34:14.591824Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1         | Version: '5.7.25'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
wordpress_1  | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
wordpress_1  | Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
wordpress_1  | Obtaining a new certificate
wordpress_1  | Performing the following challenges:
wordpress_1  | http-01 challenge for abc.com
wordpress_1  | Waiting for verification...
wordpress_1  | Cleaning up challenges
wordpress_1  | IMPORTANT NOTES:
wordpress_1  |  - The dry run was successful.
wordpress_1  |  - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
wordpress_1  |    configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
wordpress_1  |    secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
wordpress_1  |    also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
wordpress_1  |    making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
wordpress_1  | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
wordpress_1  | Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
wordpress_1  | Obtaining a new certificate
wordpress_1  | Performing the following challenges:
wordpress_1  | http-01 challenge for abc.com
wordpress_1  | Waiting for verification...
wordpress_1  | Cleaning up challenges
wordpress_1  | IMPORTANT NOTES:
wordpress_1  |  - The dry run was successful.
blog_wordpress_1 exited with code 0
wordpress_1  | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
wordpress_1  | Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
wordpress_1  | Obtaining a new certificate
wordpress_1  | Performing the following challenges:
wordpress_1  | http-01 challenge for abc.com
wordpress_1  | Waiting for verification...
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping blog_wordpress_1   ... done
Stopping blog_db_1          ... done
```

So the certbot command runs in a loop. Docker thinks that the execution isn't successful. Also Certbot says that the certs folder needs to be backed up. I'm guessing that this needs to be persisted (mounted as a docker volume). Any ideas on cleaning this up?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this, I face the same problem. Thanks ;)